# exclude custom post type from main loop wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using wordpress and have set up a couple of Custom Post Types. I need to know how to exclude these from the main look so the Custom Post Types do not show up in the blog.

Comment: By default CPTs won't show up in the loop anyway. Do you know which page template displays your custom posts?

Comment: I added the query to the front-page.php and noticed all the posts are listed in the blog.

Comment: index.php is controlling the posts by default.

Comment: Can you post the query arguments here? Posts, as in blog posts, are not custom post types, they are default and expected to be shown in the main loop.

Comment: <?php $args = array('post_type' => 'home-post' ); 
   $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
    <?php
     // The Loop
      if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      
       while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
       $the_query->the_post();
        if (has_tag('main-cta-title')) {
         echo get_the_title();
         the_content();
        }
       }
      } 
     rewind_posts(); 
    ?>

Answer (score 0):

Just replace 'post_type' => 'home-post' with 'post_type' => 'post' or delete that line and it will only pull your regular posts

Answer (score 0):

```
this code use for fetch post type data
<?php
$args = array('post_type' => 'post','posts_per_page' => -1);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<div class="entry-content">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile;?>
```